# Using an Jquery Function (Ajax call) only when the element is present

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am new to Jquery and Ajax. I am trying to use good form and keep my Ajax function calls in a separate file. My file currently consists of one function described below:

```
$("form#click").submit(function(){
     myArray =$("option.asmOptionDisabled");
     tids = []
     $.each(myArray, function(i, val) {
       tids[i] = val.value;
     });
     $("#uberloading").css("display","block");
     tids = tids.join(',%20');

     date_start = $(".date-start")[0].value;
     hour_start = $(".hour-start")[0].value;

     date_end = $(".date-end")[0].value;
     hour_end = $(".hour-end")[0].value;



     $.ajax({
        url: '/saffron_main/click_out_display?tids='+tids+'&date-start='+date_start+'&hour-start='+hour_start+'&date-end='+date_end+'&hour-end='+hour_end,
        success: function (data) {
            $('#graph').html(data);
            $("#uberloading").css("display","none");
        }
    }); 
});
```

However, when I load this file onto a page that doesn't have a form element with the class click, I get an error indicating that you can't call a .submit function on an null element. How do I ensure that the function is only loaded when there exists a form element with the class click?

Comment: what version of jQuery are you using, and what additional plugins are you using? doesn't seem to happen with 1.6.3 http://jsfiddle.net/3MY9k/

Comment: Where do you get this error?  It should just fail to find the element and hence fail to bind the `submit` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, `form#click` is a form with `id="click"` (not a `class`, as the question text says).

But the real issue here is not that there is no such form -- jQuery will have no problem with that, your handler will simply not be attached but that is all.

The problem is that the expression `$("form#click")` itself does not yield a jQuery object. There are two possible causes for this:

- jQuery is not properly included on the page that gives you this error, in which case including it will fix the problem.
- This code runs before jQuery is included in your page, in which case moving it after the `<script>` tag that includes jQuery will fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to use the `.length()` method of detecting if an element exists

```
$(document).ready(function(event) {
    if ($("form#click").length) {
         // your submit event listener logic here - or call to a function
         // containing your event listener logic (cleans up doc ready a bit)
    }
});
```

this way the event listener is only loaded IF the matching element is found on the page.

Comment: this is just in addition to @Jon reply above and directly answers Peter's question "How do I ensure that the function is only loaded when there exists a form element with the class click?" using his sample code containing the ID (and not class) that Jon pointed out